# Cannot call C# dll from VBscript in SYSPRO

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript

I am trying to call a C# dll from VBscript in via electronic signatures in SYSPRO 6.1.

I have registered the dll using regasm and I can see it in the registry entry.

I can also call it using command prompt and test .vbs file. I am using the same VBscript in both SYSPRO and the test.vbs file.

I am really at my wits end here and I am wondering if there is anything I am missing or doing wrong with regards to calling dll's from within SYSPRO or dll's in general.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SYSPRO is a 32 bit application, so if you try and run a 64 bit dll from within SYSPRO, it cannot find it because it is looking for the 32 bit version.

I solved this by registering the dll using 32 bit command prompt, regasm and then it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript only supports IDispatch. This is also known as late binding. I've heard to make C dlls you have to mark them dual interface.